# Difference between Gensim's FastText and Facebook's FastText

Tags: gensim, fasttext

I came upon the realization that there exists the original implementation of FastText [here](https://fasttext.cc/) by which you can use `fasttext.train_unsupervised` in order to generate word vectors (see [this link](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html) as an example). However, turns out that gensim also supports fasttext and its API is similar to that of word2vec. [See example here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_fasttext.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tutorials-run-fasttext-py).

I am wondering if there is a difference between the 2 implementations? The documentation was not clear **but do they both mimic the paper [Enriching Word Vectors with Subword Information](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04606.pdf)? And if yes then why would one use gensim's fasttext over fasttext ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim intends to match the Facebook implementation, but with a few known or intentional differences. Specifically, Gensim doesn't implement:

- the `-supervised` option, & specific-to-that-mode autotuning/quantization/pretrained-vectors options
- word-multigrams (as controlled by the `-wordNgrams` paramerter to `fasttext`)
- the plain `softmax` option for loss-optimization

Regarding options to `-loss`, I'm relatively sure that despite [Facebook's command-line options docs](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/options.html) indicating that the `fasttext` default is `softmax`, it is actually `ns` except when in `-supervised` mode, just like `word2vec.c` & Gensim. See for example [this source code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/a20c0d27cd0ee88a25ea0433b7f03038cd728459/src/args.cc#L29).

I suspect a future contribution to Gensim that adds `wordNgrams` support would be welcome, if that mode is useful to some users, and to match the reference implementation.

So far the choice of Gensim has been to avoid any supervised algorithms, so the `-supervised` mode is less-likely to appear in any future Gensim. (I'd argue for it, though, if a working implementation was contributed.)

The plain `softmax` mode is so much slower on typical large output vocabularies that few non-academic projects would want to use it over `hs` or `ns`. (It may still be practical with a smaller-number of output-labels, as in `-supervised` mode, though.)

Answer (score 2):

I found 1 difference from the [gensim's documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText):

```
word_ngrams (int, optional) – In Facebook’s FastText, “max length of word ngram” -
but gensim only supports the default of 1 (regular unigram word handling).
```

This means that gensim only supports **unigrams**, but no **bigrams** or **trigrams**.